# How to make a circle act like a stroke in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This is a design I'm working on:[image]

I'm okay with the logo but the only problem is that it is very inconvenient. It needs to have the path colour frequently changed, and this works well, apart from the highlighted circles. Only the stroke around these circles changes, and it is very tedious, making one have to manually disable the stroke, select the appropriate colour to fill.
[image]

Is there a way I can modify these circles so that when I change the stroke colour, the circles' colour changes as well. (The logo is a group)

I've tried using the Blob tool but it still acts like a circle.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use global color swatches, then adjust that.

Answer (score 1):

Make the circles smaller and apply a thick stroke that *looks* like a fill.

Circle with 1pt stroke.

[image]

Same circle with a 10pt stroke.

[image]

---

Or.. **expand** the strokes you do have so everything is a *fill* rather than strokes. (This is a wise move for a logo, if it's finalized, to prevent stroke weights being altered.)

---

Or.. as Joojaa points out in comments... use **Global Swatches** to change colors for everything with a simple double-click.

Comment: Thanks, Scott, but I don't quite understand the second suggestion you've made (to expand the paths). I know I've done something wrong, but I don't know what. Could you please explain further? (I expanded the paths and selected stroke in the dialog box that came up, then used a fill colour, but ended up with this: https://imgur.com/a/KxwchBL

Comment: @RedHotCoffee : Select everything *except* the background rectangle, `Object > Expand Appearance` (if it's available), then `Object > Expand`, then click the **Merge** button on the **Pathfinder Panel** (Bonus step: choose `Object > Compound Path > Make`) Everything should then be **one** object with one fill, no strokes.